# Office 365 Authentification using ASP MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with authentification with my domain (example www.contoso.com)

I tried with localhost and it works perfectly.

When I use my domain with http, the authentification works but it shows nothing (just an empty page).

When I use my domain with https it show the error

> "Error: AADSTS50011: The reply address "" does not match 
>   The reply addresses configured for the application: c6827548-2019-4372-8ab8-44a7358be82c."

(but I added https://www.contoso.com to reply URLs:)

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error.I have followed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/authenticate-and-use-services article and able to succesfully run authentication part on localmachine, but after publishing on production server i am getting said error.

As mentioned in this forum [Office 365 azure setting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a0e20dbb-fb2b-4438-a018-04ecc8b5bddf/aadsts50011-the-reply-address-does-not-match-the-reply-addresses-configured-for-the-application?forum=WindowsAzureAD), we will have to set redirect URI in azure control panel page. Is there any alternate solution, so that I can place redirect URI in code itself.

Thanks n B'Regards,
Vijay